# Minimum operations required

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across this in a recent interview.

We are given two arrays of integers and we need to check whether 1st array can be transformed to second array or not. The only operation allowed is as follows : pick any 3 adjacent elements from 1st array and right rotate them i.e. {a,b,c} => {c,a,b}. We can apply this operation any number of times.

I have tried with recursive solution but I need a better approach.
In my recursive solution, I tried to make 1st element of 2nd array equal to that of 1st array by finding its closest position from left and making required number of operations. So, when 1st element matches, I make recursive call for rest of array.
i.e. let a = {1,2,3,4} and b = {4,1,3,2}. We need to convert array a to b.
So, {1,2,3,4} => {1,4,2,3} => {2,1,4,3} => {4,2,1,3} and as a[1]=b[1], make recursive call for 2 to n.

How to solve such problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe your recursive solution in the question.

Comment: Ok, I have added my recursive solution.

Comment: With three elements, there are six possible orderings [abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba]. Three of those can be solved [abc, bca, cab] , and three cannot [acb, bac, cba]. The ones that cannot be solved are formed by swapping two elements, e.g. `acb` is formed by swapping `b` and `c`. So the solution is to count the number of swaps in the array. If the number of swaps is odd, then the array cannot be solved.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example test case ??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by counting number of swaps ?

Answer (score 0):

> We can apply this operation any number of times.

But your title is saying something else.

So, Given Two Strings S1 and S2 of size N where different alphabets count in the string is same then only we can think of transformation.
 we can match all characters from 1 to N-2
in both the strings in all cases.
Every time when we pick a character from first string, movement of that character can be 
`-2+1-2+1-2+1..............`
We can move picked character to these places back in string
`-2,-1,-3,-2,-4,-3....`
After matching N-2 characters
If last two characters were matched then we have transformed our string but they were not automatically matched then we can't do anything further.
So the problem Problem lies with the last two characters we can't do anything with two character's movement.

For example
*S1=abdc

S2=abcd*
we can't change *abdc* to *abcd* here because from *abdc* we can only go to 12 permutation out of 24 which are
*abdc, dabc, acbd, bdac, dcab, bacd, adcb, bcda, dbca, cbad, cadb, cdba*

**Optimally Fast answer By counting inversions**

Deep down it's connected to number of inversions in the string
If inversions in the both string are even or odd then only transformation is possible .

**Finding inversions in a string**

```
int invcount=0,charcount[26]={0};
for(i=0;i<s.size();i++)
{
   for(j=s[i];j<='z';j++)
   invcount+=charcount[j-s[i]];
   charcount[s[i]-'a']++;
}
cout<<invcount;
```

Comment: We know that we can easily check for last 2 characters. But, is there any better(efficient) way to get order of those 2 characters without doing any operations ? Its just needs to check whether it is possible or not and constraint given were quite big to get TLE.